# Can I bring in my dog's effects into Australia - e.g collar/lead/jumper/soft bed?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, australia, pets

He is coming with us (via quarantine) but I'm a bit confused whether it's ok to bring his personal effects with us.

I saw you have declare animal products such as real animals/dead/fur etc, but I'm not sure what the procedure is for standard pet owner items?Travelling from the UK to Australia.

Answer (score 8):

**Yes**, you can bring them, but [they are considered "used animal equipment" and must be declared at the border for inspection](http://www.agriculture.gov.au/travelling/arriving-in-australia#live-animals-and-animal-products):

> You must declare certain food, plant material and animal products.
>
> Live animals and animal products:
>
> - used animal equipment including veterinary equipment and medicines, shearing or meat trade tools, saddlery and tack and animal or bird
>     cages

Collars and leads should be fine, but the bed may be a bit iffy if it has hair etc, so you'll want to clean/wash it thoroughly first.  The customs officer will decide.  Even the worst case is just confiscation: you will not be penalized otherwise as long as you have declared them.